# Toffoli upside down - an equivalent circuit

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

It is known that an "upside-down" CNOT is equivalent to a "normal CNOT" surrounded by Hadamard gates as shown in this picture.

[image]

I am wondering whether there is a similar circuit equivalent to Toffoli gates controlled by qubits below the target qubit or with the target qubit in the middle as shown here.

[image]

The only way I was able to find so far is to take a decomposition of the Toffoli gate (e.g.[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate#/media/File:Qcircuit_ToffolifromCNOT.svg)), redraw the circuit in order to have it upside down, and replace upside-down CNOTs with the construction above.

I am looking for a more elegant way similar to that of the CNOT.

Comment: Have you tried doing hadamards on the old target and the new target?

Comment: @DaftWullie: I see and at the same time left the other control unchanged?

Comment: I think so (I've just done this in my head, not written it down, so you *do* want to check it carefully)

Comment: (How I did it in my head: $|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes I+|1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes c-not$, so use the result we know for cnot.)

Comment: @DaftWullie: It is pretty simple solution and it works. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the advice by *DaftWullie*, I added Hadamards on the target and one of the control qubits. The trick is that the Toffoli gate is in fact a controlled CNOT. So we can leave one of control qubit unchanged and consider the rest of the gate as a CNOT. Then, we can apply the same approach as in the case of an "upside-down" CNOT. Here are the equivalent circuits:

[image]